# Clustering data based on multiple variables using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have the following dataset :

```
cust_ID Phone   Email
1   A   X
2   A   Y
3   A   Z
4   B   X
5   B   P
6   B   Q
7   C   P
8   C   R
9   C   S
```

Where each unique combination of phone no. and email creates an unique customer_id is created. If a phone no or email_id repeats, i would know that it belongs to the same customer.I want to create a unique id for all these customers using the possible phone number combination.

```
cust_ID Phone   Email   ID
1   A   X   A-B-C
2   A   Y   A-B-C
3   A   Z   A-B-C
4   B   X   A-B-C
5   B   P   A-B-C
6   B   Q   A-B-C
7   C   P   A-B-C
8   C   R   A-B-C
9   C   S   A-B-C
```

How can I achieve this using R?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, rather please format the required table with text in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gives me the desired result. Let's call my sample dataset 'd'.

```
**> `

d<-d[order(d$cust_id),]

ID=d%>%
  group_by(email)%>%
  mutate(ID=first(cust_id))%>%
  ungroup()

ID<-ID[order(ID$ID),]

ID=ID%>%
  group_by(phone)%>%
  mutate(ID1=first(ID))%>%
  ungroup()

z=0
y=1


while (y!=0)
{ 
  for (i in 1:nrow(ID))

  {z<-z+ifelse(ID$ID[i]==ID$ID1[i],0,1)
  i=i+1
     }
  ID<-ID[order(ID$ID1),]

  ID=ID%>%
    group_by(email)%>%
    mutate(ID=first(ID1))%>%
    ungroup() 

  ID<-ID[order(ID$ID),]

  ID=ID%>%
    group_by(phone)%>%
    mutate(ID1=first(ID))%>%
    ungroup()

  y<-z
  z=0
}



**
`
```

final dataset:

> 

```
cust_id phone   email   ID  ID1
1   A   X   1   1
2   A   Y   1   1
3   A   Z   1   1
4   B   X   1   1
5   B   P   1   1
6   B   Q   1   1
7   C   P   1   1
8   C   R   1   1
9   C   S   1   1
```

My original dataset contains 80k rows. please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

According to your explanation, I would do that then.

I simulated data

```
cust_ID=1:50
Phone=round(runif(n = 50,100,150))
Email=round(runif(n = 50,200,250))
```

Here is an overview what it looks like (to be sure I understood correctly this time)

```
cust_ID Phone Email
   1   100   246
   2   130   221
   3   114   216
   4   120   205
   5   149   247
   6   125   208
```

I computed the following to get `finalID` which I think you are what you are looking for:

```
df=as.data.frame(cbind(cust_ID,Phone,Email))
ID_Phone=df%>%
  group_by(Phone)%>%
  mutate(PhoneID=first(cust_ID))%>%
  ungroup()


ID_mail=ID_Phone%>%group_by(Email)%>%
  mutate(finalID=first(PhoneID))%>%
  ungroup()

head(ID_mail%>%arrange(finalID),100)
```

This give that result

```
  cust_ID Phone Email PhoneID finalID
        1   100   246       1       1
        2   130   221       2       2
       36   109   221      17       2
       40   109   221      17       2
       43   143   221      11       2
        3   114   216       3       3
       41   115   216      41       3
        4   120   205       4       4
       45   122   205      45       4
        5   149   247       5       5
```

---

**Previous Post (I misunderstood)**

I would personnaly use the `dplyr` library and proceed as follow. Let say that your data is stored in the `df` variable. I would for instance consider only phone number and expose ones with several distinct `Email` values. I focus only on `Phone` but you can repeat the operation with `Email` then cluster `cust_ID`

```
df %>% group_by(Phone) 
%>% summarise(
          vector = paste(Email, collapse="__"),
          cluster_similar_phone = paste(Cust_ID, collapse="__"))
```

This command would give you a dataframe with unique `Phone`values and the corresponding `Email`. Base on your example, it should give you something like

```
 Phone      vector   cluster_similar_phone 
  A         X__Y__Z  1__2__3
  B         X__P__Q  4__5__6
              ...
```

I would maybe repeat it for email then use the column `cluster_similar_phone` and `cluster_similar_email` to group final `cust_ID`.

I am not sure if it is what you are looking for but please comment if it is not so I can edit and adapt the code.

Comment: Thanks, but i have tried this before. this is not what i am looking for. So basically, all my cust_ID from 1to 9 belong to the same person, i want to cluster them under 1 bucket. so my final unique ID against all these customers would look like "1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9" or "A_B_C" (if i create the unique_id by combining all unique phone numbers that might be associated with each of these cust_ID)

Comment: So then what about `group_by(Phone)` then reinitiliaze ID according to this group. Then you could `group_by(Email)` and use this new ID to give for instance the first ID value to all lines. I will edit my post.

Comment: I edited my post, I think it is what you are looking for. Please upvote if it is the case or mark it as a correct answer

Comment: I tried the edited version, it still does not solve my problem. So, if my Phone or Email is repeated for any of the cust_ID it belongs to the same customer. so by your simulated dataset,the cust_IDs in (1
16
20
28
35
42
44
2
5
22
34
14
15
6
43
19
) should all have finalID= 1